# REQUEST_FILENAME issues, stopped functioning with php upgrade

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

So I have a request_filename rule which has suddenly stopped working. I have recently upgraded my server to Jessie, and php upgraded with it.

However, this is the rewrite rule I have at the moment.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.URL\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/URL\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.html$ http://www.URL.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [NC,L]
```

The .htaccess file is owned by www-data and can be accessed.

I seem to see this in the error logs

```
[Thu Jun 04 19:43:21.641790 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15423] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 213.138.113.36:65331] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://www.URL.com/
[Thu Jun 04 19:43:21.641883 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15423] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 213.138.113.36:65331] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://www.URL.com/
[Thu Jun 04 19:43:21.642056 2015] [core:info] [pid 15423] [client 213.138.113.36:65331] AH00128: File does not exist: /var/www/URL/about, referer: http://www.URL.com/
```

Is it perhaps something I am not loading in my virtual host conf?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin EMAIL@hotmail.com
        ServerName URL.com
        ServerAlias www.URL.com
        ServerAlias *.URL.com

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev

        DocumentRoot /var/www/URL

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/URL.error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/URL.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is a website I took over hosting, I don't usually work with .htaccess files. Any advice would be appreciated.

The issue I have is the pages try to load as www.url.com/about This fails as the file is about.html.

Comment: Just curious not really the issue but what version of Apache is this? It appears to be 2.4 from the error log but you are using 2.2 directives such as `Order allow, deny`

Comment: 2.4.10-10, perhaps that is the issue then? Should I Remove that line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few things going on here. I don't see a Directory Directive for the actually document root. Which then would not be using the .htaccess file because there is no `AllowOverride All` specified for your document root. Also you shouldn't use 2.2 directives in 2.4. Change your Vhost file to look like this. I modified it slighty and added the directory Directive for your root.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin EMAIL@hotmail.com
        ServerName URL.com
        ServerAlias *.URL.com

        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV dev

        DocumentRoot /var/www/URL

        <Directory "/var/www/URL">
                Options -Indexes -MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride All
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/URL.error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug

        CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/URL.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the my main apache2.conf file.

AllowOveride was disabled.

I made the following change

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I said in my answer. Except putting it in your vhost like I did for your specific domain keeps .htaccess off for other sites where it might not be needed. Allowing it for `/var/www/` will allow it for every site under www.

Comment: I posted this without seeing your answer, I apologise.